# Problem with constant dynamic array of classes

Tags: arrays, class, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to use a constant dynamic `array of TClass` but the stored values are not valid. When I use a constant static `array[0..xx] of TClass`, this is correctly working.
Here is a sample code :

```
const
     _CtrlClasses      : array[0..2] of TClass
                       = (TPresentedTextControl,TTextControl,TCustomEdit);
     _CtrlClassesDyn   : array of TClass
                       = [TPresentedTextControl,TTextControl,TCustomEdit];
//     _CtrlClasses      : array[0..2] of integer
//                       = (1,2,3);
//     _CtrlClassesDyn   : array of integer
//                       = [1,2,3];

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   i : integer;
begin
     with Memo1.Lines do
     begin
          Add('Static :');
          for i:=Low(_CtrlClasses) to High(_CtrlClasses) do Add(format('%x',[integer(_CtrlClasses[i])]));
          Add('Dynamic :');
          for i:=Low(_CtrlClassesDyn) to High(_CtrlClassesDyn) do Add(format('%x',[integer(_CtrlClassesDyn[i])]));
     end;
end;
```

The result, stored in Memo1, is as follow :

```
Static :
79FA84
6F9C88
7F7EFC
Dynamic :
79FADC
6F9CE0
7F7F54
```

The correct values are the ones below "Static :". In the case of the dynamic array, an constant offset ($58) is added to the stored value.
Could you help me ?

Comment: Confirm this behaviour in Tokyo (10.2). Note that dynamic array being filled in code rather than in const section, works properly.   $58 is `vmtSelfPtr` for 32-bit Windows target

Comment: @MBo, thank you for testing. I've posted an "issue" to Embarcadero.

Comment: Probably pointless,  but did you try with TArray<TClass>?

Comment: @Ken Bourassa: I've tried TArray<TClass> and it is the same behaviour.